# Can i get the Visible Column Width out of total column width in ListView with Horizontal scrollbar

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a ListView with View as Details & one of the column has comboboxes to edit the data for each row.

When I resize my columns I am getting a horizontal scrollbar within my ListView in Form. Suppose if I move the second column such a way that half of the column is visible & half can be visible only when scroll is dragged to right.

Can I get this Visible column width of the ListView in any way??

Rgards

Comment: Sharing an image about what you need may help more.

Comment: I thought you meant the visible width of the last column. To get at the visible widths of any column one will have to know about the amount scrolled or maybe plug into a draw event... I'll play with it a little later but don't hold your breath..

Comment: Hi, Please remember to mark a relevant answer as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can programatically step through each column in your `listview`, and get its width.

You can then do the math to calculate the visible area of the column, by using each columns width, and the listview's width itself.

Here is working code. I left it quite simple, to show the steps. You can optimise it for your usage.

```
        Dim totalWdith As Integer = SOlistview.Width
        Dim combinedColumnWidth As Integer = 0
        Dim visibleSpaceLeft As Integer = 0

        Dim columnCount As Integer = SOlistview.Columns.Count
        Dim weHaveClipping As Boolean = False

        For i = 0 To columnCount - 1

            If combinedColumnWidth + SOlistview.Columns(i).Width > totalWdith Then

                '//we will have clipping occur if we add this column...

                visibleSpaceLeft = SOlistview.Width - combinedColumnWidth
                weHaveClipping = True
                Exit For

            Else

                '//no clipping yet, so add this column to my math

                combinedColumnWidth += SOlistview.Columns(i).Width

            End If

        Next

        Dim myDropDown As New ComboBox

        If weHaveClipping Then
            myDropDown.Top = e.Y - myDropDown.Height
            myDropDown.Left = combinedColumnWidth
            myDropDown.Width = visibleSpaceLeft
        Else
            '//run your normal code to place the combobox....
        End If


        SOlistview.Controls.Add(myDropDown)
```

You can also modify it to spit out just a width, and then use your calcualted visible width whenever you need to (Like on a scroll that happend, mouse click etc)

```
        private function _get_clippedColumn_visible_width() as int16

        Dim totalWdith As Integer = SOlistview.Width
        Dim combinedColumnWidth As Integer = 0
        Dim visibleSpaceLeft As Integer = 0

        Dim columnCount As Integer = SOlistview.Columns.Count
        Dim weHaveClipping As Boolean = False

        For i = 0 To columnCount - 1

            If combinedColumnWidth + SOlistview.Columns(i).Width > totalWdith Then

                '//we will have clipping occur if we add this column...

                visibleSpaceLeft = SOlistview.Width - combinedColumnWidth
                weHaveClipping = True
                Exit For

            Else

                '//no clipping yet, so add this column to my math

                combinedColumnWidth += SOlistview.Columns(i).Width

            End If

         Next

         return visibleSpaceLeft 

        End Function
```

Comment: Thanks Louis...But how do I calculate??I mean on ListView_MouseUp event I am checking the ListViewItem.SubItems[1].Width but its getting me the total width of that column and not the visible width. It would really help if you help me out with sample code.

Comment: I am not at a dev pc now, but measure the width of the listview, - (minus) the combined width of you first columns up to your last columns that is being clipped.

Comment: a More interesting question would be, what are you trying to achieve? Why are you looking for the visible width?

Comment: Actually I am placing a Combobox control within that column on ListView_MouseUp event whenever user clicks on any ListViewItem. I am calculating the selected ListViewItem  respective column width & assigning it to Combobox.Bounds and this worked fine without scrollbar. But this was failing when a horizontal scrollbar comes up since the ComboBox is not physically part of the ListView control, the ComboBox does not automatically scroll with the ListView.<https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/320344> Followed article which I have followed to implement.

Comment: I see, it makes more sense now.

Comment: I added working code, its in vb.net, but you should get what I am doing.

Comment: Thanks Louis...But that worked partial. I mean when I was only resizing my columns in the ListView the combobox width in listview column was placed correctly but when I just scrolled the horizontal scrollbar then the combobox was not correctly placed within the width of the visible column area. This was because when we used scroll the combinedcolumnwidth is still the same but the scrolled amount was changed which did not change it, so it was showing me a bit smaller combo than what size was expected in the column. Hope you understood me.

Comment: Yes, as I said, you have to adjust the code Its a proof on concept. Figure out when you are moving the scrollbar, and adjust your comobox width on the fly. This needs to be extended to perfectly match what you want. I only showed you "how" this type of thing can be done.

Comment: You keep adding more criteria. Maybe update your question to include all the relevant criteria.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96775/discussion-between-deepthi-and-louis-van-tonder).

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest you to work with the TableLayoutPanel to get more opportunities.